# Post request problem with nextjs and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm coming from the "Java world" and creating a small web program for the first time with: NextJS, React, Postgres and axios.

When I create the Login/Signin pages, I succesed to communicate with the server and send with post requests.

My problem is when I tried to send the post messages outside the render() of react, Its send the route without the url host, and the server doesnt get the post request. **(When i send the post request with Postman its working).**

I know it's a server/client sending requests problem , but I've been sitting on it for a few days and can not solve the problem.

So here is a limited repo of my web program: https://github.com/idonava/react-next-program-example

**SignIn - working post request flow:**

1. *pages/signin.js* handleSubmit -> signIn (line 103).
2. *libs/auth.js* signIn-> authenticate (line 16).
3. *services/authApi.js* authenticate-> post(line 6).
4. *services/requets.js* post send request via axios(line 8).
5. After that - the server get the post request, return answer to the client and the user login succesfully

**Getting the user id- NOT working post request flow:**

1. *pages/flickr.js* getInitialProps -> getUser (line 15).
2. *libs/user.js* getUser-> getCurrentUser (line 4).
3. *services/authApi.js* getCurrentUser-> post(line 26).
4. *services/requets.js* post send request via axios(line 8).
5. the server doesnt get to post request, And it look like the url is "/routing/getuser" instead of "localhost:3100/routing/getuser".

notes:

- The program run locally on localhost:3100.
- The server listening for the request on *server.js* -> *routing/index.js* -> *db/models/user*.

I'd be happy to get help with that.
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You shouldn't make backed calls from `render()` but from `componentDidMount()` and use state or observables to render again. What do you mean by outside `render()`? Could you share your code? How are you making a the post request?

Comment: @FortyTwo Hi! All relevant code has been attached- https://github.com/idonava/react-next-program-example